# Identifying and marking single and multiple account holders in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I'm currently obsessed with this SQL issue. I have the following table

```
`account_id` `person` `account_type`

     001       eric         PH

     001       lucy         SH  

     002       stacy        PH  

     002       Chris        SH  

     002       Ruud         SH  

     003       Angel        PH
```

The table shows that there are people that share an `account_id` e.g. 001 and 002. The `account_type` column identified whether the person is the Primary or Secondary Holder of the account.

The people with `account_id` 001 and 002 should get a 1 value in a new column named `multi-account`.

If the person is a single account holder, the `multi-account` value should be 0.

Expected output

`account_id` `person` `account_type` `multi-account`

```
 001       eric        PH               1

 001       lucy        SH               1  

 002       stacy       PH               1

 002       Chris       SH               1 

 002       Ruud        SH               1 

 003       Angel       PH               0
```

How would you recommend to solve this in SQL? I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question?

Comment: Show us the expected output as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks Tim, yes i did ask the question before. But i had to clarify some things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to compute which accounts have been assigned to more than one person.  If so, the following `UPDATE` statement should do the trick:

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.multi-account = CASE WHEN t2.personCount > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM accounts AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT account_id, COUNT(DISTINCT person) AS personCount
    FROM accounts
    GROUP BY account_id
) AS t2
    ON t1.account_id = t2.account_id
```

This answer assumes that you already have a column called `multi-account` in your table.  If not, then create it via:

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD multi-account BIT
```

Comment: excellent tim, exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for the clear info. voted up!

Comment: Happy to help.  Next time you ask a question try to show sample input and output.  You will get an answer much faster.